# How I should open .ipynb as new notebook version in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I reinstalled my vs code, then, when I open the .ipynb in vscode, I also reinstalled the jupyter plugin. But I found the old notebook version opened.
Before I reinstalled these programs, they were still new versions.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using Anaconda Navigator to download & use a virtual environment that could be easier to use in most cases.To use the virtual environment use -
<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> or **Python: Select Interpreter command** from the Command Palette.However,please make sure to add environment variables to your VS-Code.

Otherwise,best bet may be to use the *Jupyter* notebook from Anaconda Navigator which pretty much does the same thing

Comment: thank you, I read the new version description document in Microsoft net. I installed the last insider version of vscode, that's ok. haha.